# Returning value of a cell, where another cell matches between sheets

Tags: excel

I've been doing various tutorials on MATCH and INDEX but I'm struggling with this and starting to wonder if it's possible without getting too complex?

I have an Excel file with 2 sheets, both contain a lot of rows.

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve, in rough terms, for F2 shown is:

```
WHERE ('sheet 1' product_id == 'sheet 2' product_id) RETURN
value in column D WHERE column C == 'Gem'
```

Perhaps I'm missing an easier way of doing this? The idea is to populate each column (gem, colour, metal, birthstone) based on the information in Sheet 2. There is too much data to do this manually. Also note every product_id has each attribute, for example a metal ring won't have value in Sheet 2 for 'gem'.

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided sample data, put this formula in Sheet1 cell F2 and copy down (adjust ranges to suit your actual data):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$20,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$20=A2)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$20="Gem"),),0))
```

Comment: @SomeGuy The cell F1 in your provided example image is "Gem" so that's how it's getting the word "Gem".  As for the issue of it prompting to pick a file, that's kind of strange.  I would venture a guess that you don't actually have a worksheet named `Sheet2`.  If that is indeed the correct name, try surrounding all references to `Sheet2` in single quotes: `=INDEX('Sheet2'!$D$2:$D$20,....`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion that I've created. I think you're right about the reference. The curious issue now is that it works fine until cell F7. At this stage, and for all other cells going down, it returns N/A. The value of F7 for your reference is: =INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$20,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$20=A2)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$20="Gem"),),0)). I checked Sheet2 and there is a Gem value declared - it's not in the original screenshot, but it appears in row 21. This is because, you will notice there is no birthstone on row 16, so it goes out of sync.

Comment: That's because you're using limited references. If you replace the row number 20 in that formula with the row number of the last data row,  then it should work too.. e.g. `INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$743,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$743=A2‌​)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$743​="Gem"),),0))` if the last row was 743

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I hadn't noticed the hard coded end points in his solution. Which should I accept as the answer as I believe both now appear to be working!

Comment: Up to you. I believe Tigeravatar came in first, so tick his answer if its fine fr you...

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$D, MATCH($A2&F$1, Sheet2!$A:$A&Sheet2!$C:$C, 0))`

Put that in F2 and press Ctrl-Shift_enter. Then drag down. Can use for other columns as long as the headers match exactly the attributes in Sheet2! column C

Comment: This appears to be working, it takes a while but I guess it's a relatively complex task (albeit with a very small formula, thanks!). I will do a bit more testing, but curious to know if cell can be set blank rather than '0' if there is no attribute declared? It's not 100% necessary, but for completeness.